# Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in

Tags: configuration, installation

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 29

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php:81 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory.php(157): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get('default') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\Type\Config.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool->get('config') #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config->_getFrontend() #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader.php(73): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->load('global::DiConfi...') #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load('global') #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php(187): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(208): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory), 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(36): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create('C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array) #14 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php on line 81

Comment: PHP Version ?????

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the version of php you are using. Please use version from php 7.4.x or below.